# accessing DELETE from jquery in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

If I am sending data from my ajax request as type:delete

How do I then access it on my php page instead of $_GET or $_POST

?

Answer (score 1):

Using the other, oft-forgotten HTTP request methods is referred to as REST or a RESTful application.

Here's a PEAR module which gives you the ability to work with that: http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request/

> Supports GET/POST/HEAD/TRACE/PUT/DELETE, Basic authentication, Proxy, Proxy Authentication, SSL, file uploads etc.

I found that [on this page](http://www.sematopia.com/?p=153), which also discusses how to use it.

These functions might be of use too: [HTTP extension](https://www.php.net/HTTP)

Answer (score -1):

You can access the URI for a DELETE request just like any other request in the `$_SERVER` super global: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

From there you can parse any parameters you've created.  You might find [the class](http://phprestsql.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/phprestsql/PHPRestSQL/phprestsql.php?revision=1.12&view=markup) created for the [phprestsql project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phprestsql/) to be a useful reference.