# get a PHP delete variable

Tags: php

If I am issuing an HTTP DELETE, how can I access the PHP body/variable? I know if you're issuing POST, you access it via `$_POST['varname']`, but how do you access it if it's a DELETE not POST? Say the varname here is ID.

Comment: It is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405505/accessing-delete-from-jquery-in-php but I don't know whether the answers help you.

Comment: Checked that out, doesn't help me

Comment: You can get variable in `$_GET`. If the method is not `GET` and `POST` request will be sent as `GET` method

Comment: I was half right with the `parse_str` idea, see my answer for an easy way parse the the `PUT` and `DELETE` request variables from the HTTP request body. There are limitations however.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might have to look at reading the data directly from the `php://input` stream.

I know this is how you have to do it for `PUT` requests and some quick googling indicates that the method works for `DELETE` as well.

See [here](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2008/Accessing-Incoming-PUT-Data-from-PHP) for an example. The comment [here](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2008/Accessing-Incoming-PUT-Data-from-PHP#c1559) says this method works for `DELETE` also.

Here is an interesting code sample that will help (from sfWebRequest.class.php of the symfony 1.4.9 framework altered slight for brevity):

```
public function initialize(...) 
{
  ... code ...

  $request_vars = array();
  if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']))
  {
    switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
    {
      case 'PUT':
        if ('application/x-www-form-urlencoded' === $this->getContentType())
        {
          parse_str($this->getContent(), $request_vars );
        }
        break;

      case 'DELETE':
        if ('application/x-www-form-urlencoded' === $this->getContentType())
        {
          parse_str($this->getContent(), $request_vars );
        }
        break;
    }
  ... more code ...
}

public function getContent()
{
  if (null === $this->content)
  {
    if (0 === strlen(trim($this->content = file_get_contents('php://input'))))
    {
      $this->content = false;
    }
  }

  return $this->content;
}
```

This code sample puts the `PUT` or `DELETE` request parameters into the `$request_vars` array. A limitation appears to be that the form (if you are using one other the content-type header) must be 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', some quick googling confirms this.

Comment: And so say after doing this, then I can access it via $request_vars['id']?

Comment: Yes, essentially. You won't be able to use the code as is because it's part part of a large class, but it's the template you're after.

Answer (score 6):

[`file_get_contents('php://input')`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) should always give you the complete request body. Note that it may be readable only once. The bigger question is whether a DELETE request may contain a body, which seems to be something of an [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request), but will *probably* work.

I'd say sending the id in the body is somewhat RESTless though. The entity in question should be referred to by the URL as `example.com/foo/42`, so a DELETE request should say `DELETE /foo/42`, not `DELETE /foo` with the id in the request body.

Comment: then how do I get the specific variable name? do I have to string parse it?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by people above, PHP does *not* have a global variable to quickly access data in a `DELETE` request. Why, I do not know; it probably hasn't been as used as `GET` and `POST` historically.

You would have to check the request type using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` and then retrieve the entire body using the `php://input` stream and extract your data from that. You could create a function that does this on every request and saves it in a global variable named `$_DELETE` if you would like to keep a similar look to your code (assuming you use `$_POST` and `$_GET`). You could even patch your PHP to do this and compiling your own version of PHP, but that would of course confuse people who try to run your code on another PHP installation :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access it in a globally available array, but you can determine the request typer, see here: [Detecting request type in PHP (GET, POST, PUT or DELETE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359047/php-detecting-request-type-get-post-put-or-delete)

Comment: I can detect it just fine, I want to get the var.