# Axios DELETE request body being sent empty

Tags: php, ajax, axios

I'm trying to send a delete request to my PHP/Codeigniter api. Sending it from a NativeScript-Vue frontend.

```
 async deleteBackedupImages(identifiers) {
        console.log(identifiers);
        try {            
            var { data } = await axios({
                url: this.apiUrl + "/images?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=dsadsad",
                method: "delete",
                data:{
                    identifiers
                },
                headers: { "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest","Content-Type": "application/json" }
            });
            return data;
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }
```

On the PHP side of things, i have this function to take care of the JSON data:

```
function getJSONData():stdClass{
    try {
        $ci =& get_instance();
        $stream_clean = $ci->security->xss_clean($ci->input->raw_input_stream);
        $request = json_decode($stream_clean);
        return $request;
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {    
       throw $th;
    }

}
```

"identifiers" is just an array of strings.

$stream_clean variable comes out as an empty string, instead of JSON string.

I have to say it's a bit weird, that Axios docs state the following:

> // `data` is the data to be sent as the request body   // Only
>   applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', and 'PATCH'

I've seen on various posts, that a data object **can** actually be sent with a delete request.

What could be the problem with my code?

Comment: _“I've seen on various posts, that a data object can actually be sent with a delete request.”_ - referring specifically to Axios, or just whether a DELETE request can have a body or not in general? What you quoted from the docs might simply indicate that Axios does not send a body when `method: "delete"` is specified, not matter whether you supply `data` or not …

Comment: You know what the problem with your code is: you're trying to send a DELETE request with a body, which has no defined semantics. Even if Axios sends it, many server implementations ignore it.

Comment: Posts claiming that an Axios delete request can be sent with a body. Like this one:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51069552/axios-delete-request-with-body-and-headers Also this one: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/897

Comment: Well then maybe the server side part doesn’t care for a body on DELETE requests. Is this CodeIgniter? Have you researched whether that handles a body on DELETE requests the way you want to begin with?

Comment: 04fs, i thought about this, but the interesting thing is that it works 100% when sent using Postman :D It's possible of course that "postman does something different", but i have no clue what.

Answer (score 3):

Use params instead of body to send DELETE requests with Axios:

```
var { data } = await axios({
   url: this.apiUrl + "/images?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=dsadsad",
   method: "delete",
   params:{
      identifiers
   },
   headers: { "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest","Content-Type": "application/json" }
});
```

Note that according to [Axios Documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config)

```
// `params` are the URL parameters to be sent with the request
// Must be a plain object or a URLSearchParams object
```

Answer (score 0):

For the php people out there. PHP doesn't parse the request body when doing a delete / put so the $_POST data stay empty. You can grab the input by using

```
file_get_contents('php://input');
```

thansk to [get a PHP delete variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374796/get-a-php-delete-variable)

Spent a whole afternoon trying to figure this out. In most cases it's probably easier to use the params option of axios. More details here: [HTTP protocol's PUT and DELETE and their usage in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941207/http-protocols-put-and-delete-and-their-usage-in-php)