# My ajax delete is not passing data to the controller. Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, sql-delete

### CODEIGNITER

I'm trying to delete an instance in the db using an ajax delete request. I'm  trying to pass data with the id of the instance I want to delete.

In my javascript when i use 'type:POST' in my ajax call the code works correctly and the data is deleted but when i use `type:DELETE`it doesn't work.

JAVASCRIPT AJAX CALL

```
$(".complete").click(function(){
    var title = this.id;
    //console.log(title);
     $.ajax({
       url: '/ajax-requestDel',
       type: 'DELETE',    <!-- when i use type:'POST" the code works
       data: {title: title},
       error: function() {
          alert('Something is wrong');

       },
       success: function(data) {
           console.log(data);
       }

    });
});
```

CONTROLLER CODE

```
    public function ajaxRequestDelete(){
       $data = $this->input->post('title');
       return $this->db->delete('todo', array('title'=>$data));
    }
```

When debugging i have found that the variable $data is empty but when using a post call it has the desired value.

How do i repeat the same behavior using delete. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data will arrive at the php input stream `php://input` for a `DELETE` request.

You should use `$this->input->input_stream('title');` as per the [manual](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html)

See also: [get a PHP delete variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374796/get-a-php-delete-variable)